# Ionic React navigation with a parameter when used in conjunction with the browser back button completely breaks navigation

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, router

This issue is a problem in both versions of @ionic/react 7.4 and 7.5.

I have two simple routes defined as follows:

```
<IonRouterOutlet id="main">
...
<Route path="/campaigns" exact={true} render={props => <CampaignList {...props} />} />
<Route path="/campaign/:title" exact={true} render={props => <CampaignDetail {...props} />} />
...
</IonRouterOutlet>
```

The first route displays a list and each list item has an `onClick` method defined which calls a method titled `getCampaignDetail` which navigates to the second route as follows:

```
const getCampaignDetail = (title:string) => {
  navigate(`/campaign/${title}`, 'root');
}
```

When i load my app, it defaults to `/campaigns`

That view loads without issue and displays the list

If i tap a list item it correctly navigates to `/campaign/:title`

**Then, i use the browser's back button** to load `/campaigns`

The `/campaigns` view loads without issue

**Then, upon tapping a different list item** i can say that i am **absolutely positive** that it attempts to load a different `:title` because:

1. i am console logging the value before it navigates and seeing the value is clearly **different**
2. The URL in the browser **clearly** is showing as though the parameter `:title` is different and has changed from the last time i visited this route

Despite this, when i console log the `:title` in the `CampaignDetail` component which is what loads at `/campaign/:title` inside it's `useIonViewDidEnter` method, the `:title` is printing as though its value **has not changed** from the first time i visited `/campaign:title`

In my `CampaignDetail` component i have tried retrieving the parameter in one of 2 ways, first directly from props:

```
type MatchParams = {
  title: string;
};
const CampaignDetail: React.FC<RouteComponentProps> = (props) => {
const { title } = props.match.params as MatchParams;
...
```

And also with the `useParams` hook:

```
const CampaignDetail: React.FC<RouteComponentProps> = (props) => {
const { title } = useParams<{ title: string; }>();
...
```

and it is in the `useIonViewDidEnter` method, where i am attempting to console log `:title`

```
useIonViewDidEnter(() => {
  console.log("PARAMETER:", title);
});
```

**This behavior only occurs after having used the browser's back button.**

Why is the parameter not reflecting the correct value for subsequent visits after having used the browser's back button?

**In an attempt to fix this after reading documentation and doing other research into this issue I have tried adding a `key` to the route as a solution as follows**:

```
<Route path="/campaign/:title" exact={true} render={props => <CampaignDetail key={props.match.params.title} {...props} />} />
```

however, this results in **EVEN WORSE BEHAVIOR** in that after having used the browsers back button subsequent visits to `/campaign:title` cause the `useIonViewDidEnter` method to execute **several times** and with each execution i am seeing the `:title` act as if it is toggling between the two values i have visited with each print to the console. First i see the value as it was for the first time i visited, then the new value, then it prints the first value and so on about 3-4 times before it finally stops.

Seeing that behavior speaks volumes in that having used the browser's back button clearly causes strange behavior with respect to route parameters.

What can i do to fix this?

**UPDATE:**

I am noticing that when i hit the browser's back button while at the route `/campaign/:title` that the `useIonViewDidEnter` function in the component `CampaignDetail` is firing again when it **should not** given that i had left that route and navigated back to `/campaigns`.

**OTHER ODD BEHAVIOR:**

As per @Aafaq's suggestion that i check `location` as a means of troubleshooting, i did this and have discovered strange behavior as a result.

If i comment out the `useIonViewDidEnter` method all together and use the following `useEffect` hook with `location` to check for path changes as follows:

```
  const campaignDetailTitleRef = useRef('');

  useEffect(() => {

    const parts = location.pathname.split('/');
    const getPathTitle = parts[2];

    if (getPathTitle && getPathTitle !== campaignDetailTitleRef.current) {
      campaignDetailTitleRef.current = getPathTitle;
      console.log("PARAMETER:", getPathTitle);
    }
  
  },[location.pathname]);
```

When the app loads which launches the route `/campaigns` and then i click on a list item, i see that `console.log("PARAMETER:", getPathTitle);` only prints once as expected when `/campaign/:title` loads and it is displaying the correct value as it was parsed from `location`.

**Then i hit the browser's back button**, and subsequently, i click a different list item, and while the value of `getPathTitle` is actually printing correct now having retrieved that value from `location` instead of params, i am seeing `console.log("PARAMETER:", getPathTitle);` **print twice** which tells me that either `campaignDetailTitleRef.current = getPathTitle` is not getting set after the hook runs the first time or the component is loading twice, it is hard to tell which is the case. It is difficult to troubleshoot what is happening.

Something as simple as page navigation with just one dynamic parameter in the url should not be so difficult. This renders Ionic React worthless in a browser at this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrapping routes with the `<Switch>` component makes sure that only one route is matched at a time and works to prevent the behavior i described.

There is one caveat to this solution which is to say that Ionic navigation forward and back animation between routes will not work.

I see this as acceptable for a web based deployment and not a hybrid app, given that for a hybrid app that runs in a webview, this issue does not exist and in which case the `<Switch>` component can be excluded.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to use the **useLocation** hook from **react-router-dom** to log the current location and its state for debugging purposes. This can help you identify any unexpected behavior related to route changes. Example given below:

```
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

const CampaignDetail: React.FC<RouteComponentProps> = (props) => {
  const { title } = useParams<{ title: string }>();
  const location = useLocation();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    // ... Logs for debugging purpose
    console.log('Location:', location);
    console.log('Title:', title);
    // ... You can put rest of your logic here
  }, [location, title]);
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, i tried this and updated my post to reflect what i found. This is still an issue.